# Solution for optimizing web menu bar

Tags: javascript, menu, usability, menubar

I'm working with a product that has a web-based interface. The functionality is huge and is divided into modules. Access to each module is via a drop down menu available on all pages. Each menu item has at least 2 levels of drill downs (vertically)

Problem: Too many top level menu items

- Solution 1: Group Elements (Logically) so that the top menu   fits.
- Solution 2: Reorganize Menu items using the mega-menu technique (à la republic.co.uk)
- Solution 3: A menu that's   smart enough to know how many   elements to show and adds a '>>' sign   at the left end. On hover/click/flick   of the '>>' sign, the menu scrolls   horizontally to reveal the remaining   elements, also placing a '<<' sign at   the right end.
- Solution 4: (better than solution 3...) ?

Solution 1 and 2 will need a lot of soft skills, time and energy... I've love to have solution 3 or 4 .. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you first need to find out which solution is better for the user, before solving the technical details. You can do that by organizing usability testing. It can be a pretty lightweight process if you use the techniques as described by Steve Krug in Rocket Surgery Made Easy. (Or his previous book, don't make me think).

If you need another solution: why not have a single ajaxy autocomplete search box that contains all the possible module access menu items? That way the user doesn't need to scroll through a lot of lists and you keep the visual clutter to a minimum.

Comment: point taken. And I really like the autocomplete search box idea. Thanks!